# How to integrate Mixpanel analytics to a Django backend?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, mixpanel

I need to track all notifications in my Django backend using mixpanel analytics. Does anyone have any ideas or resources of how I can integrate it to my project? PS: I am using celery to handle the notifications asynchronously. Thanks

Comment: you can use [this](https://github.com/sayonetech/mixpanel-django-graphos) repo to implement https://github.com/sayonetech/mixpanel-django-graphos

Comment: Thanks a lot!. Exactly what I was looking for.